# Make File Upload Not Required On Edit

Tags: module, grid, grid-serlization

I have created a module that is more or less a CRUD app. One of the fields is for a file to be uploaded. When I edit one of the rows, it is requiring me to re-upload the file to save the edit.

Is there anyway to make that one field not required when editing an row?

Edit: Here is the code I am using to add the file upload control to the form

```
$fieldset->addField('filepath', 'file', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('batch')->__('Select PDF'),
              'required'  => true,
              'name'      => 'filepath',
    ));
```

Comment: You made something wrong. What type did you use in your form? If you use Image or File, there should be a hidden field generated which contains the filepath, a checkbox to delete and a file-upload to change the file

Comment: I took a look at the page source, I did not see any hidden field with the filepath... hrmm, is it because maybe filepath is a reserved input name?

Comment: You want it to not be required, and you have `'required' => true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.
First of all in the admin controller if your entity you should have something like this:

```
Mage::register('current_entity', $entity);//key and var name may differ
```

Instead of your code use this:

```
$settings = array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('batch')->__('Select PDF'),
    'name'      => 'filepath',
);
if (!Mage::registry('current_entity')->getId()){// if on "add" mode (use the same registry key as in your admin controller)
    $settings['required'] = true;
    $settings['class'] = 'required-entry';
}
$fieldset->addField('filepath', 'file', $settings);
```